# Download branches from Github

Tags: github

I want to download https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ecmascript from Github, and I do not have git installed, and there is not download as zip option, what is the fastest way to get it downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a branch, just a subdirectory in the git repository. You can download the entire repository as a zip by going on https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 and then just discard the files you don't need.

And in the case of projects that do have branches, you can easily switch to the other branch using the *branch selector* on the top-left of the screen. Then, the "Download ZIP" button will reflect that branch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as it is just 3 or 4 files, use the 'raw' option maybe? For example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/ecmascript/ECMAScript.g4